# Как отфильтровать ненужные картинки?

Tags: парсер

Столкнулся с проблемой. Хочу написать парсер картинок. Структура такая: вводишь `url`, он берёт страницу и собирает все картинки. Но среди этих картинок получается много лишних. Такие как: кнопки соцсетей, элементы дизайна, звёздочки, иконки. Как можно заставить парсер собирать только адекватные картинки. Какие есть идеи?

Задумывался фильтровать по размеру картинки, если он указывается. Например, если размер картинки меньше 100*100, то её не берём.

Какие ещё будут идеи по фильтрации ненужных картинок?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о имеджбордах, то там может быть общая тенденция в названии картинок в галерее. Например, один раз парсил такое: картинка имеет от 1  тега. Название выглядело как "тег1-тег2-тег3.jpg". Правда некоторые картинки имели на сайте название длиннее максимально допустимого названия в ОС.

Comment: Не... тут будет такая фишка типа пользователю даётся возможность ввести любой URL он туда вписывает его и оно парсит любой сайт... ему выдаёт заголовок, описание и картинки... и он выбирает нужную ему картинку и постит её с описанием и заглавием... так вот неохото чтобы пользователю на выбор предлагался всякий спам... Тоесть к вёрстке сайта толком не прикрепишься... и к url картинки тоже...

Comment: С размером x*x  не угадаешь, в тегах может не быть размера.
Ну как крайний вариант, это смотреть вес картинки, в мегабайтах например. Мелочь отсеивать сходу. Вопрос лишь в том, что бы определить вес картинки.
На мой взгляд это фиговый вариант: придётся брать саму картинку и вытаскивать размеры уже из неё.

Comment: Или писать оооочень умный парсер, анализирующий контекст :)

Comment: что-то мне это гугл напомнило, интересно какой у него фильтр

Comment: Ну размер файла думаю получать через getimagesize(); поэтому размер определить можно будет... я планирую задать 3 размерных грани..
w>80px и h>80px
w>150px и h>60px
w>200px и h>40px

и ещё запустить проверка на наличие в url к картинке слова logo если присутствует то брать любой размер...

Вес картинки - тоже хороший варинт - но как его определить??? может кто подскажет?

а может проще считать площадь картинки? например чтобы картинка содержала не менее 10000 пикселей. тогда пропорции картинки могут быть любые. за идеальные берётся 100*100 пикселей...

Comment: Забей на вес. Подумал: ужасный вариант. Для этого надо качать картинку из сети. Долго, ненадёжно, память не резиновая.